# How to decode AAC format(mp4 audio file) to PCM format in Android

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, pcm, aac, mediaextractor

I have an mp4 file with only one audio track in AAC format. I would like to convert this mp4 file to an audio file in PCM format. I can extract the audio file in AAC format from the mp4 file successfully. But I can not decode AAC format to PCM format.

The following code works without any errors and saves the PCM data to a file. But this audio in PCM format can not be opened with any media player. It says that the file is corrupted. I tried to decode AAC format to PCM format with ffmpeg and there is no problem with ffmpeg. But I do not want to use ffmpeg library because of the library size.

Firstly, I tried to give the mp4 file path to inputfilePath and the output file is created and saved successfully. But this output file is not opened in any media player.

extractAudioFromVideo(".../input.mp4", ".../output.wav");

Secondly, I extracted the AAC audio file from the mp4 file successfully. And I tried to give the ACC file path to inputfilePath and nothing changed in the output.

extractAudioFromVideo(".../input.aac", ".../output.wav");

static void extractAudioFromVideo(@NonNull String inputfilePath, @NonNull String outputFilePath) {

```
    try
    {
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);

        MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        extractor.setDataSource(inputfilePath);

        MediaCodec mediaCodec = null;
        for(int index = 0; index < extractor.getTrackCount(); index++)
        {
            MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(index);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if(mime.startsWith("audio/"))
            {
                extractor.selectTrack(index);
                mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                mediaCodec.configure(format, null, null, 0);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (mediaCodec == null)
        {
            Log.e("Converter", "Can't find audio info");
            return;
        }

        mediaCodec.start();

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();

        boolean isEOS = false;
        while (true)
        {
            if (!isEOS)
            {
                int inputIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
                if (inputIndex >= 0)
                {
                    ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inputIndex];
                    int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                    if (sampleSize < 0)
                    {
                        Log.d("Converter", "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                        mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                        isEOS = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                        extractor.advance();
                    }
                }
            }

            int outputIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
            switch (outputIndex)
            {
                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                    Log.d("Converter", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                    outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
                    break;
                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                    Log.d("Converter", "New format " + mediaCodec.getOutputFormat());
                    break;
                case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                    Log.d("Converter", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                    break;
                default:
                    ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outputIndex];
                    /*
                    // I tried this line of code but it gives the same result.
                    byte[] chunk = new byte[info.size-info.offset];
                    int position = buffer.position();
                    buffer.get(chunk);
                    buffer.position(position);
                    outputStream.write(chunk,0,info.size-info.offset);
                    */
                    final byte[] chunk = new byte[info.size - info.offset];
                    buffer.get(chunk);
                    buffer.clear();

                    if (chunk.length > 0)
                    {
                        outputStream.write(chunk,0,info.size - info.offset);
                    }

                    mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputIndex, true);
                    break;
            }

            if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0)
            {
                Log.d("Converter", "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                break;
            }
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        mediaCodec.stop();
        mediaCodec.release();

        extractor.release();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Should I do something more than this line of code to save it in PCM format or Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Hasan. Are you sure the File is being written in correct format? Check for the proper file format here http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat

Comment: Thank you Rahul. Your answer is very helpful. I supposed that the problem is related to the raw data. But my problem is that I am not converting the raw file to the wav file in the correct way. The following link solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281430/how-to-convert-pcm-file-to-wav-or-mp3

Comment: Glad to know that!